# Creating a simple javascript inventory object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have been given an code stub for an inventory object as one of my assignments for my javascript module, under instruction to flesh it out to create an inventory which includes methods to add, and remove items from an items array. I'm struggling to figure out how to fill out the methods and was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction.

The code stub is:

```
var inventory = {
items: [],
add: function(item) {},
remove: function(index) {}
};
```

After a bit of googling I believe the methods i should be using are;

```
items.push("")
items.splice("")
```

however i'm unsure how to slot them into code stub i have been provided.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This question is too basic. Try to figure it out by yourself. Use MDN (e.g. type "mdn.io/push" into the browser's address bar).

Comment: They did try to figure it out "After a bit of googling..." Give them a break. If it's easy answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you already seem to have a fairly defined structure to your inventory I feel like this might be a better alternative. This way you could look items up by name instead of saving the index.

```
var inventory = {
    items: {},
    add: function(key,item) {
        if (item !== null)
            this.items[key] = item
    },
    remove: function(key) {
        this.items[key] = null
    },
    get: function(key) {
        if (this.items[key])
        {
           return this.items[key];
        } else {
           return null; 
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems a much more logical way to do it than i was provided!

Comment: @JoePerkins the answer has syntax errors and not using `this` inside functions for getting the items

Comment: Sorry about the errors. I'll be sure to edit it and post the update shortly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inventory = {
  items: [],
  add: function(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
  },
  remove: function(index) {
    this.items.splice(index, 1);
  }
};
```

Comment: why would anyone down-vote this is beyond me

Comment: I spotted this question in the close vote review queue; I suspect someone observed that this question is probably homework and (perhaps a little over-zealously) downvoted all the answers too.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do that:

```
var inventory = {
    items: [],
    add: function(item) {
        items.push(item);
    },
    remove: function(index) {
        items.splice(index,1);
    }
};
```

Of course, check index.length before removing...
**But** it would be best to remove your inventory 'class' to just use an array, don't you think?